# DSC cannot create SSL/TLS secure channel in the SendConfigurationApply function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, dsc, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to add a vm scale set to an agent pool in Azure Devops. I have set up the VMSS and now am adding DSC as an extension which will then call "SendConfigurationApply" to send to the agent pool.

However when I upgrade the VMs I get this error:

> VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'DSC'. Error
> message: "DSC Configuration 'AgentsInstalled' completed with error(s).
> Following are the first few: The request was aborted: Could not create
> SSL/TLS secure channel. The PowerShell DSC resource
> '[AgentsResource]Agents' with SourceInfo
> 'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.83.1.0\DSCWork\agentsConnectedInt.ps1.1\agentsConnectedInt.ps1::26::9::AgentsResource'
> threw one or more non-terminating errors while running the Set
> functionality. These errors are logged to the ETW channel called
> Microsoft-Windows-DSC/Operational. Refer to this channel for more
> details. The SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed." More
> information on troubleshooting is available at
> https://aka.ms/VMExtensionDSCWindowsTroubleshoot

I have set the protocols on the VMs to use TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

The VMs are on an older version of Windows 10 client because we need to run Edge Legacy. Could that be related to this issue?